# How can I use bluetooth to transfer files between my iPhone 6 and my Windows 10 laptop?

Tags: iphone, windows, bluetooth, file-transfer

I had the (possibly mistaken) belief that one of the functions of Bluetooth was to easily transfer files between two nearby devices. I could certainly do this with my Android phone and my Linux laptop.

I now have an iPhone and a Windows laptop for work and I can't seem to transfer files between the two. Is one or other of the operating systems crippled in some way, or am I doing something wrong? The devices are paired* but sending files does not succeed.

> * well they used to be. Windows still thinks they are, but iOS is now saying my laptop "is not supported" (something changed in recent update to iOS 11???)

Comment: Nearly 4,000 views on this. Yet another example of Apple's idiotic decisions that prevent users from completing basic tasks and having basic freedoms with their software.

Comment: A year later: 26K views.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

iOS 11.x does not support sending files using the [Bluetooth OBEX protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange). So unfortunately you can't transfer files using this method.

You may be able to transfer files over Wi-Fi with apps like [FileExplorer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fileexplorer-file-manager/id510282524?mt=8).